# Padding out a bitmap to make it a power of two

Tags: android

I have a bunch of images of dimension 480x800. The intention is that these will fill the entire screen of the device.

I would like to take the image and use `createScaledBitmap()` to resize the image to fit the screen exactly. I then want to put this bitmap inside another bitmap (not stretch it), which will have dimensions that are a power of two.

So for example, if the screen size is 320x480 I resize my 480x800 image to be 320x480. I then want to place this 320x480 image inside of a bitmap that is 512x512 so that the original image is nested in the top left corner (with the extra space being blank).

How can I achieve this on android? I have gotten so far as to resize the image to fit the screen exactly, but not making the power of two bitmap and filling it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a texture atlas